# How to launch an app, without bringing it to the foreground?

Tags: android, android-intent

On Android, I wrote a service, which would launches an app with

```
Intent intent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(pkg);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

This will bring the "pkg" to the foreground.

**Question:** how to launch this pkg to the background? which won't disturb the using of current foreground app.

Comment: @blackbelt, I did use service, but "getLaunchIntentForPackage(pkg)" still brings "pkg" into foreground.

Comment: What's the point of launching an app if you don't want the user to see the UI?

Comment: @Simon I am glad that you understand my question. The purpose is for some optimization which intends to reduce the launch time.

Answer (score 0):

You're certainly looking for a [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). Service in Android is used to run operations in background and for longtime.

> A Service is an application component representing either an
>   application's desire to perform a longer-running operation while not
>   interacting with the user or to supply functionality for other
>   applications to use.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html). A `Service` acts as an `Activity` that is without `View`.